# Scoped dependency injected as transient into MassTransit Consumer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, masstransit

I am using Azure Functions v3, MassTransit and Azure Service Bus. Once Azure Function reads a message off the Service Bus `MyConsumer` is called. I noticed my **scoped** dependency `Foo` is not injected correctly into Azure Function and `Myconsumer` - instead of the same instance being injected in both Azure Function and `MyConsumer`, they each get a separate instance. Is there a way for Azure Function and `MyConsumer` to both get the same scoped dependency injected? Am I missing something?

Azure Function Startup.cs

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{   
    builder.Services.AddScoped<Foo>();
    builder.Services.AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<MyConsumer>();
    });
}
```

Class I want to inject as a scoped dependency.

```
public class Foo
{
    // Just a way for me to test which instance is injected.  
    public int MyProperty { get; set; } = new Random().Next();
}
```

Function

```
class MyAzureFunction
{
    private readonly Foo foo;
    private readonly IMessageReceiver receiver;
    
    public MyAzureFunction(IMessageReceiver receiver, Foo foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    [FunctionName("MyAzureFunction")]
    public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("topic-name", "subscription-name", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")] Message message)
    {
        await receiver.HandleConsumer<MyConsumer>("topic-name", "subscription-name", message, default(CancellationToken));
        // foo.MyProperty is 3456411
    }
}
```

Consumer

```
public class MyConsumer : IConsumer<IMyEvent>
{
    private readonly Foo foo;

    public MyConsumer(Foo foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IMyEvent> context)
    {
        // foo.MyProperty is 78961248, indicating a different instance has been injected.
    }
}
```

Comment: There are separate scopes for the function and the consumer.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson: Yeah, I figured that's the case, but I wanted to double check. Thanks for getting back so quickly.

Comment: Any way to make them share the same scope? My DB context has a property (`tenantId`) set before the consumer's `HandleConsumer` method is called, which is null inside the consumer because the scope is not shared.

Comment: We have the same "problem" in the context of ASP.NET Web application. I explained it more clearly and give the solution here: https://github.com/duongphuhiep/blog1/wiki/Learn-MassTransit#each-masstransit-requests-has-its-own-scope-which-is-different-from-the-http-request-scope